Button behind select is clicked too (with Shadcn)
I have built a form where users have a select drop-down from which they can pick a product category. I am using a select from Shadcn. When I open the select and pick a category, it fires the button placed just behind the selected option. Based on what I have read, this is a Shadcn/Radix issue. Maybe someone here found a workaround for the same problem.
<form
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    className='flex flex-col bg-white px-8 pt-1 pb-8 mt-6'
>
    <label htmlFor='name' className='mb-1 mt-1'>
        Product Name
    </label>
    <input
        className='mb-4 border-b-2'
        id='name'
        name='name'
        type='text'
        placeholder='What do you wish to rent?'
        value={input.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
    />
    <label htmlFor='description' className='mb-1 mt-1'>
        Product Description
    </label>
    <input
        className='mb-4 border-b-2'
        id='description'
        name='description'
        type='text'
        placeholder='Describe your product'
        value={input.description}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
    />
    <label htmlFor='location' className='mb-1 mt-1'>
        Pick up address
    </label>
    <input
        className='mb-4 border-b-2'
        id='location'
        name='location'
        type='text'
        placeholder='Where to pick up your tool?'
        value={input.location}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
    />
    <div className='flex flex-row justify-between'>
        <label htmlFor='dailyRate' className='mb-1 mt-1'>
            Daily rate
        </label>
        <input
            className='mb-4 border-b-2 w-20 mt-1'
            id='dailyRate'
            name='dailyRate'
            type='number'
            placeholder='€'
            value={input.dailyRate}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
        />
    </div>
    <div className='flex flex-row justify-between'>
        <label htmlFor='weeklyRate' className='mb-1 mt-1'>
            Weekly rate
        </label>
        <input
            className='mb-4 border-b-2 w-20 mt-1'
            id='weeklyRate'
            name='weeklyRate'
            type='number'
            placeholder='€'
            value={input.weeklyRate || ''}
            onChange={handleChange}
        />
    </div>
    <div className='flex flex-row justify-between mt-1'>
        <label htmlFor='monthlyRate' className='mb-1'>
            Monthly rate
        </label>
        <input
            className='mb-4 border-b-2 w-20'
            id='monthlyRate'
            name='monthlyRate'
            type='number'
            placeholder='€'
            value={input.monthlyRate || ''}
            onChange={handleChange}
        />
    </div>
    <div className='flex flex-col justify-between'>
        <label htmlFor='image' className='mb-4'>
            Product image
        </label>
        <Input id="picture" type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} className='bg-darkGreen p-2 text-white text-sm rounded-md pl-8'/>
    </div>
    <div className='flex flex-row justify-between mt-4 mb-10'>
        <label htmlFor='category' className='mb-1 mt-5'>
            Category
        </label>
        <Select
            onValueChange={(value) =>
                handleSelectChange('toolCategoryId', value)
            }
            name='toolCategoryId'
            value={input.toolCategoryId}
        >
            <SelectTrigger className='w-45 mt-3'>
                <SelectValue placeholder='Select a category' />
            </SelectTrigger>
            <SelectContent>
                {categories.map((category) => (
                    <SelectItem key={category.id} value={category.id} onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
                        {category.categoryName}
                    </SelectItem>
                ))}
            </SelectContent>
        </Select>
    </div>
    <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
        <button
            type='submit'
            className='bg-darkGreen pt-4 pb-4 pl-20 pr-20 text-white text-sm rounded-md'
        >
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
 


You can use stopImmediatePropagation() in the event.
